# xfce instantly terminates if I set scale to 2, giving Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, display, xfce, xrdp

I have a headless ubuntu, I've tried this with official Canonical Azure image and also with official Canonical docker image. The result exactly the same.

I've installed `xfce` and `xrdp` and `xorgxrdp`. I can successfully create a remoted xrdp session from my Windows home machine both using MS's `mstsc` both MobaXTerm.

I have 4K display, so I want to set scale 2. I can not set in the GUI, because althoug it allows to pick the value 2 to pick from the dropdown list, after pressing Apply button, nothing happens, and instantly set back to 1.

So I've tried to set it in the configuration file:

```
sudo vim /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml
```

then set `WindowScalingFactor` to `2`

```
<property name="Gdk" type="empty">
    <property name="WindowScalingFactor" type="int" value="2"/>
</property>
```

After restarting the session, the logon screen appears, and after giving my credentials and pressing [OK], the session instantly terminates.

Here is the .xsession-errors file content:

```
Xsession: X session started for myuser at Fri Nov 24 07:19:28 UTC 2023
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:11.0
localuser:myuser being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=myuser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/myuser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SINK_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SOURCE_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=myuser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SOCKET_PATH=/run/xrdp/sockdir
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:11.0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SESSION=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/myuser
xfce4-session-Message: 07:19:28.648: SSH authentication agent is already running
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one
/home/myuser/.xsession: line 1: 18732 Segmentation fault      xfce4-session
```

Although a fatal error of segmentation fault is an error in the software itself which's fixing is beyond our scope, still my use case is so usual and nothing special extra it is possible I am missing some trivial configuration and/or installation step. Also note, I've reproduced the excactly the very same issue both on my Azure host, and my Docker host, so no those image specifics, neither infa specifics do not play a role...

What possible thing could I miss here?

Comment: (1) The only thing that prevents me from upvoting the "question" is the lack of any actual, explicit question. You can [edit] and fix this. (2) "Segmentation fault" usually indicates a bug. Maybe there are workarounds, but most likely the real solution involves fixing `xfce4-session` itself.

Comment: many thanks for your suggestions. Agree segmentation fault is a fatal. I was just hoped. maybe it not a core functionality programming error, just the lack of handling something missing parameter, configuration, etc (like missing a default branch in a switch statement with a clear error log message, and instead going forward with a null pointer) This case giving xfce the missing something what I did not know about may peacefully solve the issue and the xfce guys will handle the missing parameter within a few decades, whith a meaningful log message